# How to remove slash from entity android

Tags: android, json, httpentity

I'm trying to form a request param like below,

```
{"keywords":"Fufh",
"tootiText":"",
"email":"davmooray@gmail.com",
"tweetDate":"2016-05-07T13:04:03.019+0530",
"isFavorite":"false",
"cultureName":"en-GB",
"longitude":"79.819694",
"rating":"0",
"latitude":"11.9528747",
"weatherType":"0",
"thumbnailColor":"#0076BF",
"measureTooteets":"[{"value":"3","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":1,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true},{"value":"3","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":26,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true},{"value":"4545","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":26,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true}]"}
```

using the below method

```
private Request createMeasureTooteet(Tooteet tooteet) {
        Map<String, String> params = getParamsForMeasure(tooteet);
        Log.d("ss","Create Measure param_____________"+params.toString());
        HttpEntity entity = ApiUtils.getEntity(params);
        try {
            Log.d("ss","Create Measure entity 1_____________"+EntityUtilsHC4.toString(entity));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ((StringEntity) entity).setContentType(HeaderUtils.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);

        try {
            Log.d("ss","Create Measure entity 2_____________"+EntityUtilsHC4.toString(entity));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new Request(TooteetType.NOTE, entity, tooteet);
    }
```

Where i'm getting log like below,

```
Create Measure param_____________{tootiText=, keywords=Gdfyvj, email=davmooray@gmail.com, tweetDate=2016-05-07T13:55:16.635+0530, isFavorite=false, longitude=79.8200781, cultureName=en-GB, weatherType=0, latitude=11.9534879, rating=0, measureTooteets=[{"value":"5","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":1,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true},{"value":"3","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":26,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true},{"value":"9","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":18,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true}], thumbnailColor=#0076BF}
Create Measure entity 1_____________{"keywords":"Gdfyvj","tootiText":"","email":"davmooray@gmail.com","tweetDate":"2016-05-07T13:55:16.635+0530","isFavorite":"false","cultureName":"en-GB","longitude":"79.8200781","rating":"0","latitude":"11.9534879","weatherType":"0","thumbnailColor":"#0076BF","measureTooteets":"[{\"value\":\"5\",\"startDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"measureTypeId\":1,\"endDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"isTimeSet\":true},{\"value\":\"3\",\"startDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"measureTypeId\":26,\"endDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"isTimeSet\":true},{\"value\":\"9\",\"startDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"measureTypeId\":18,\"endDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"isTimeSet\":true}]"}
Create Measure entity 2_____________{"keywords":"Gdfyvj","tootiText":"","email":"davmooray@gmail.com","tweetDate":"2016-05-07T13:55:16.635+0530","isFavorite":"false","cultureName":"en-GB","longitude":"79.8200781","rating":"0","latitude":"11.9534879","weatherType":"0","thumbnailColor":"#0076BF","measureTooteets":"[{\"value\":\"5\",\"startDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"measureTypeId\":1,\"endDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"isTimeSet\":true},{\"value\":\"3\",\"startDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"measureTypeId\":26,\"endDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"isTimeSet\":true},{\"value\":\"9\",\"startDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"measureTypeId\":18,\"endDate\":\"1970-01-01T00:00:00\",\"isTimeSet\":true}]"}
```

After converting params to entity slash gets append in my request like above. But my request must be send like below

```
{"keywords":"Fufh",
"tootiText":"",
"email":"davmooray@gmail.com",
"tweetDate":"2016-05-07T13:04:03.019+0530",
"isFavorite":"false",
"cultureName":"en-GB",
"longitude":"79.819694",
"rating":"0",
"latitude":"11.9528747",
"weatherType":"0",
"thumbnailColor":"#0076BF",
"measureTooteets":"[{"value":"3","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":1,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true},{"value":"3","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":26,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true},{"value":"4545","startDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","measureTypeId":26,"endDate":"1970-01-01T00:00:00","isTimeSet":true}]"}
```

How to remove slash from entity? Please suggest me any idea..

Comment: slashes are used here to keep the ( " ) in your String.. it prevent to take it as String declaration. It is used to keep the formatting.

Comment: why you want to remove slashes?

Comment: Do you see my param and enitity log: In Params MeasurTooteets is going as JSON array. Where as in entity it is going as String. So we are not getting response from the server. That is the issue we are facing. can you please give any idea to it?